# iOS Remote Notifications not being sent to iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, ssl, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I am using Firebase to send remote notifications to my iOS app but recently my remote notifications being sent do not display on the phone. After debugging the app and studying the console log I noticed that the phone was receiving the signal from the server for the notifications but seems to encounter a TLS-related error  as shown in the screenshots below.

[image: console log snapshot]

I have updated all the certificates and profiles involved in building the app and the app builds fine with no errors, but I am not sure how to progress in solving this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Heyo, here's what I have found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67308054/sendemptypushnotification-to-gateway-push-apple-com-no-longer-working/67309911?noredirect=1#comment118996327_67309911